# Is there a formula to list all possible 2 card combinations of 4 playing cards in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

### Example:

Is there a formula to list all possible 2 card combinations of 4 playing cards?

4 playing cards:

```
A♥
A♦
A♣
A♠
```

The result should be 6 combinations only (Not 4 x 4 = 16 Combinations):

```
1: A♥ A♦
2: A♥ A♣
3: A♥ A♠
4: A♦ A♣
5: A♦ A♠
6: A♣ A♦
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A4&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A4)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A4&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A4))), CHAR(9)))," "), 
 "where Col1 <> Col2", 0), "select Col1", 0)<
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A4&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A4)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A4&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A4))), CHAR(9)))," "), 
 "where Col1 <> Col2", 0), "select Col2", 0), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A4&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A1:A4)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A4&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A4))), CHAR(9)))," "), 
 "where Col1 <> Col2", 0), ), "where Col1 <>''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly for 4 cards. 

I also tried 52 cards but I get the error message: 

Error - Text result of REPT is longer than the limit of 32000 characters.

Would you know how to overcome for this case?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vb4nRL91E63eD0YPMmf_ly0Sb3RI_lVEfJI_EeFqBDU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @user0, are you available to help me with another formula? 

I explained what I am looking to do in this sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B9ap95YcORO1rRgaVK18PMye71VbJfzBjVbNxSaQm0I/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance :)